# Generating a.out file format with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, executable

How do I generate the a.out file format with GCC on x86 architectures?

With [NASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) I can do this easily with the *-f* flag, for example:

```
nasm -f aout start.asm
objdump -a start.o

start.o:     file format a.out-i386-linux
start.o
```

On Linux, compiling .c files produces an ELF object file. How can I produce *a.out* files with GCC?

Comment: Which system are you using? I don't think Linux supports a.out executables anymore. I don't know about intermediate object files.

Comment: I believe the kernel can be configured with a.out support, but that it's off by default. It's been a while since I compiled a kernel, that may no longer be the case.

Comment: Linux does support it if `CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT` is enabled at compile time.

Comment: "[a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out)" is *both* the name of a ***file format*** (abbreviated form of "assembler output") and a (literal) ***default output file name***. Confusing. Especially if the file format is deprecated and the default file name is not (and its content is no longer in a.out format, but in some other format).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To generate the a.out format with gcc, your linker needs to be told to do so. You can do it by passing it flags from gcc thanks to the `-Wl` flag.

Here is what you would do for the a.out format:

```
gcc -Wl,--oformat=a.out-i386-linux file.c -o file.out
```

You can also display all formats supported by typing:

```
objdump -i
```

Comment: the problem is, I have many object files (.o) which are in elf format, so when I link them with OUTPUT_FORMAT(a.out-i386-linux)
 parameter in the linker script i get this error: "can not represent section `.comment' in a.out object file format". This is why I need the "gcc -c file.c" being compiled from the beginning into a.out format, and not ELF.

Comment: I found the solution to the above, with -fno-ident option .comment section wasn't generated, i booted my a.out kernel fine with grub. thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed your first comment, and glad that you found the fix yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the post *[Re: How can I control the gcc's output format?](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2006-04/msg00262.html)*, you need to build `gcc` for a different target (*i386-aout*).

It sounds plausible as *a.out* has been deprecated for years (10+).

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question. One is that you'll need to compile a fresh GCC with *aout* as its target; it's not as simple as flipping a command-line switch. The other answer is a question: why do you actually need this? I can't immediately think of a valid reason.

Comment: I am developing an operating system and I need kernel and applications to be packed together in one image file so it is loaded quickly with one read and one write (the whole image) , a.out looks to be the ideal format for this, being simple and supported by a lot of bootloaders.