# What is this "a.out" file and what makes it disappear?

Tags: c, gcc

I am new to C programming. When I tried to compile it, I got an *a.out* file (I don't know where it came from) and it somehow disappeared. What is happening here?

Here are the commands I ran:

```
$ gcc hello.c
$ ls
a.out hello hello.c

$ a.out
a.out: command not found

$ gcc a.out
a.out: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ ./hello
Hello, world!$ ./a.out
bash: a.out: No such file or directory

$ ls
hello hello.c
```

Comment: `a.out` is the default name given to the built executable. You can change it with the appropriate command-line option for your C compiler.

Comment: As for why it's disappearing, we can only guess (which is bad, and makes your question off-topic btw), but I've had cases where an overprotective antivirus would do that.

Comment: This `a.out: file not recognized: File truncated` is done by `gcc` itself. No mistery there.

Comment: This must be a mega dupe. This is one of the first things a beginner runs into when compiling a C program on Unix-like systems (or only with older versions of compilers?).

Comment: *a.out* is claimed to have been [deprecated since the early 2000s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303536/generating-a-out-file-format-with-gcc/8303623#8303623). Is this in [a Turbo C++ environment](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-bitter-truths-about-engineering-in-India/answer/Adhokshaj-Mishra)?

Comment: *"a.out is a* ***file format*** *used in* ***older*** *versions of Unix-like computer operating systems for executables, object code, and, in later systems, shared libraries."* ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out). My emphasis). Though the ***file name*** "a.out" may still be used.

Answer (score 30):

`a.out` is the default executable name generated by the `gcc`. Once you invoke `gcc a.out` (which you really shouldn't - as it is passing `a.out` as an *input* to `gcc`), it is trying to create a *new* `a.out`, but failing as it is trying to read the existing `a.out` as a *source* file, which it is not. This is what making it "disappear".

If you want `gcc` to generate an executable with specific name, use the `-o` switch followed with the desired name:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

will generate the executable named `hello`, which can be run using

```
./hello
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention that the proper usage is `gcc -o hello hello.c` to get an executable named `hello`.

Comment: @unwind Sure. Will do

Comment: Maybe add that `gcc a.out` tries to create a `a.out` file using `a.out` as a C source file.

Comment: The option `-Wall` should be added too.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Well, this is not a question about `gcc` command line options. If the OP is interested, he can go to the dedicated documentation.

Comment: *"which you really shouldn't"* can you add explaination as to why one shouldn't do this...

Comment: @Yatin The explanation is following this remark, but added the same into it,  check it out.

Comment: Once you have the output file generated as `hello`, what's the difference between calling `hello` vs. `./hello`? Why does only `./hello` work and not the other?

Comment: @Honey https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331075/why-do-you-need-dot-slash-before-executable-or-script-name-to-run-it-in-bas

Answer (score 4):

`a.out` is the default executable, since you didn't tell GCC what to name it (by using `-o`). Just typing `a.out` won't run it, because it's in the current directory, and Linux doesn't put the current directory in the path like other broken OSes do, so you have to type `./a.out` to run it.

You later typed `gcc a.out`, which erased it, and tells gcc to try to compile the executable as if it were a C program, which makes no sense, so the `a.out` it produced is empty.

What you meant to do was:

```
gcc hello.c
./a.out
```

Or even better:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
./hello
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd suggest you use

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

This will create an executable called "hello" rather than the default "a.out". Of course you can call it whatever you want.